# How to rerender with setState using the same value in MaterialUi Snackbar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an Input and when the user submits a value which does not exist a not found message is shown for example `setError("Not found")` in the Toast (Snackbar) which closes after timeout. I am using Material UI and i am using it as its shown in this example [Consecutive Snackbars](https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/#consecutive-snackbars) in the docs. Only difference i made is i put this in a seperate component and added useEffect like this

```
const Toast = ({message}) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
   if(message) {
     setSnackPack((prev) => [...prev, { message, key: new Date().getTime() }]);
   }
}, [message])
 ... // Rest of the code from the docs
}
```

And this works when the error is set but if the same errors occurs (same value) it wont show the value (Snackbar)like in the example as it will not rerender because it has the same value.

My question is how would i cause the rerender so that the same string appears again, or is there a different way I could do something like this as I feel this is an anti-pattern?

Comment: Using the date-time as an id/key is probably not helping. Try using an id generator that is guaranteed to provide unique ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understood your problem, but I suspect you might not be managing the Snackbar's `open` state properly. I suggest making sure that it's always set (or inherited from the parent) correctly (e.g. not just set once upon state initialization).

The code below allows displaying a Snackbar with identical parameters multiple times. See [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-herschel-93psq) for a fully working example.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Snackbar from "@material-ui/core/Snackbar";

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState();
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <input onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => setShow(true)}>Show it</button>
      <Toast show={show} hide={() => setShow(false)} message={text} />
    </>
  );
}

const Toast = ({ message, show, hide }) => {
  return (
    <Snackbar
      open={show}
      autoHideDuration={1000}
      onClose={hide}
      message={message}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change message to an object

```
let message = {
                  messageText: "A bad thing happened...",
                  timestamp: 1626698144204
}
```

Then in your handler, update the timestamp.  Then the useEffect should fire when the timestamp gets updated.